# What does it means $f(x) \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces

> What does it means $f(x) \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Does it means that $\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)| dx < \infty$ and $|f(x)| < M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes. It means exactly this.

Comment: Yes, if you take the second condition to be true for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and assuming the $L(\mathbb{R})^\infty$ is a typo and $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is meant instead.

Comment: $f\in\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ don't necessarily imply that $f$ is bounded for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ but for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So, really, no--but it is nearly this, you have just left off some technical detail. Also, to be notationally correct, you should write "$f$", not "$f(x)$", because $f$ is the name of the function whereas $f(x)$ is the value of the function at a specific point $x$ (a real number). So: $f\in\mathscr L^1(\mathbb R)\cap \mathscr L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$

Comment: @MPW it's a bit more than just a technical detail

Comment: @krirkrirk : Call it what you will. But OP is thinking about the implications correctly. For example, if $f$ is continuous, it's correct; that's the simple first take on the statement.

Comment: It would be better to write $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ instead of $f(x) \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.  Unless you mean the values of the function $f$ are themselves functions.